# How do I know my dog fleas are gone

Tags: dogs, fleas

I have noticed my dog has fleas I've noticed about 5-6 fleas running around her belly we have problems with cat in the yard so I put it down to this.

I've used bob martin flea killer. And about to bomb every room out incase they're in my home too.

How do I know they're gone for sure?